# Confused about the order of determiners

Tags: articles, determiners

the last two books

the two last books

Like the phrase" the two best friends"(I think)  the latter would be correct.
......

my last two books

my two last books

I am confused which of those could be correct!

Comment: Google up "[order of determiners](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/determin/ordering.htm)" - and [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-position-and-order)

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, what about my question?

Comment: The links I provided directly relate to it. (0: Using the explanations there, you might try to pick the right sentences, and expand your question telling which sentences you consider correct and why.

Comment: The rule says: the + ordinal + noun or the + ordinal + cardinal + noun. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer:

USE THIS: ***the last two** books*
BUT NOT: *<del>the two last books</del>*

USE THIS: ***my last two** books*
BUT NOT: *<del>my two last books</del>*

Your examples are not similar to ***the two best friends*** because ***best*** is an adjective, not a determiner (or not a postdeterminer, to be specific).

---

#### Grammar points:

The two links given by CopperKettle (one on [The Internet Grammar of English](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/determin/ordering.htm) and the other from [English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-position-and-order)) are almost "just enough", but because neither mentions clearly what would be the order of ordinal and cardinal numbers when they co-occur, I decide to post this answer.

Let's review the basics. I'll base my explanation on [English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-position-and-order), but either source (or any of most grammar books) should be fine.

**Where do determiners go?** -- Determiners come first in noun phrases, before adjectives and noun modifiers. The basic order is:

> **determiner(s) 　 adjective(s) 　 noun modifier(s) 　 head noun**

For example, in *three big, old kitchen tables*, *"three"* is a determiner, *"big, old"* are adjectives, and *"kitchen tables"* is the head noun. (You can divide *kitchen tables* further, but it's not really relevant to our discussion, which is about ordinal and cardinal numbers.)

> <sup>​　　　　SIDE NOTE: And this is why we write ***the two best friends***, not <del>*the best two friends*</del>.
>
> ​　　　　*The* is an article, which is a determiner; *two* is a number, which is another determiner; but *best* is an adjective.
>
> ​　　　　So, *best* must be right next to *friends*, which is the head noun of *the two best friends*.</sup>

**More than one determiner** -- When there is more than one determiner in a noun phrase, we put them in a fixed order:

> **quantifier 　 article 　 demonstrative 　 possessive 　 number**

Here are some of these determiners:

- quantifier e.g. *all, both, some*
- articles: *a/an, the*
- demonstrative: *this, that, these, those*
- possessive: e.g. *my, her, our, Anna’s*
- number: *one, three, 26*

So, it's now clear that ***the***, which is an article, and ***my***, which is a possessive pronoun, must come before ***last*** and ***two***. But which comes first: *last* or *two*?

---

#### Ordinal and Cardinal Numbers

To decide which comes first between *last* and *two*, you need to know that *last* is an "ordinal number" and *two* is a "cardinal number".

An **ordinal number** is about the position of something in a series, e.g., *first, second, third, ..., last* are ordinal numbers.

A **cardinal number** is about counting: *one, two, three, ..., 41, 42,* and so on.

When we use both ordinal and cardinal numbers, **the ordinal number comes first**.

> "When a cardinal number and an **ordinal number** modify the same noun, the ordinal number always precedes the cardinal number:
>
> - The *first* two operations were the most difficult to watch.
> - The *second* three innings were quite dull.
>
> In the first example, the ordinal number *first* precedes the cardinal number *two*. Both *first* and *two* are determiners. In the second example, the ordinal number *second* precedes the cardinal number *three*. Both *second* and *three* are determiners. Try reading the sentences with the ordinal and cardinal numbers reversed. They simply sound wrong."
> (Michael Strumpf and Auriel Douglas, The Grammar Bible. Owl Books, 2004)
> <sub>([via: About Education](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/ordnumberterm.htm))</sub>

---

So, to answer your question once again, these are correct: ***the last two** books*, ***my last two** books*.